# how to receive $_POST on the same page

Tags: javascript, php

I'm currently working on a drop-down list form.

There are 2 objectives.

1. page should not refresh after the submit function is fired.
2. automatically submit if there's a change of value selected on the drop-down list.

The drop-down list is located on a modal, and the form is submitted on the same page which is the modal.php. I have used a JavaScript function that automatically submit if there's a change of value selected on the drop-down list. Now the problem is that, the receiving end doesn't work and the page is refreshing, which removes the modal.

Can you advise? Thanks

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    echo "ITS WORKING";
}

------------

<form id="result_form" name="resultform" action="" method="post">
    <select id="result_dropdown" onChange=selectChange(this.value)>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</form>

-------------------

<script>
    function selectChange(val) {
        $("#result_form").submit();
        console.log(val)
    }
</script>
```

note: all codes above are on the same page (modal.php)

Comment: Look into AJAX. PHP doesn't process client side so a refresh is required.

Comment: @user3783243 Ok, thanks, can i use the current page on ajax's url?

Comment: The reason the page is loaded because you are using form.submit() which means you submit the form to the server, and then reload the page. What you need is AJAX function in place of form.submit()

Answer (score 0):

**on client side**

First you need to replace onchange="form.submit();" to another function on the game (i.e. onchange="reloadMyForm(**YourFormObject**)" where YourFormObject is whatever form you are sending in). If you don't want to send any object in, make sure that your form has an ID, so that you can retrieve the form object from the page using document.getElementById or $().

Second, wrap the display area area inside a HTML element, such as a div. Give the element an ID for you to use once you get the information back from your server.

Third implement the function you use in onchange on the page. The function will use Ajax (XMLHTTPRequest and such) to send the data you collect from the form. The script should send the data to your server as asynchronous. Then wait for the result to come back (using onreadystatechange or similar).

Fourth, once you retrieve the response from your server (i.e. respondText or anything similar), manipulate the result and display it out on the display element you have on your page.

**Back End (server side)**

It could be another PHP file, but you have to make sure that the data sending method from your AJAX matches what you are retrieving from the back end (i.e. sending GET from ajax must use $_GET to retrieve). Another part is that when you return the data, return it as a format that your AJAX can retrieve (i.e. text, xml, etc.). One more thing, you need to be careful on this part that your script won't take too long to process, or the client side would be waiting.

Comment: I guess Ajax is the answer to all my questions. thanks

Answer (score 0):

use exit(); to stop refresh page and print dropdown value

```
if(isset($_POST["result_dropdown"])) {
   echo $_POST["result_dropdown"];
   exit();
}
```

set attribute name in select tag

```
<form id="result_form" name="" action="" method="post">
<select id="result_dropdown" name="result_dropdown" onChange="selectChange(this.value)">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: if you don't want to refresh a page use Ajax to submit form.